# Google Cloud IPsec VPN: Proposal mismatch in IKE SA (phase 1)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are trying to connect an IPSec VPN to our customer but having a hard time to get it to work.

The VPN-settings that we received from client:

- IKE Version: 1
- Authentication: PSK
- IKE Hash: SHA1
- IKE Encryption: AES 256 CBC
- IKE DH Group: 5
- Remote IP: <*hidden*>
- PSK: <*hidden*>

Now, if I create an IPSec VPN with this in Google cloud then I get this error:

```
Status: Proposal mismatch in IKE SA (phase 1). Found inconsistency
between proposals, Consider updating the following parameters:
DIFFIE_HELLMAN_GROUP,ENCRYPTION_ALGORITHM
```

In the logs I'm seeing this:

```
initiating Main Mode IKE_SA vpn_<_hidden_>[453] to <_hidden_> 
generating ID_PROT request 0 [ SA V V V V ]
sending packet: from <_hidden_>[500] to <_hidden_>[500] (156 bytes)
received packet: from <_hidden_>[500] to <_hidden_>[500] (40 bytes) 
parsed INFORMATIONAL_V1 request 0 [ N(NO_PROP) ]  received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN
error notify  The peer gateway notifies: Proposal mismatch in IKE SA
(phase 1) , Please look at peer logs.
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already found answer on https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-vpns#set_up_the_peer_vpn_gateway :

Additional parameters for IKEv1 only:

- **IKE/ISAKMP**              aes128-sha1-modp1024
- **ESP**                     aes128-sha1
- **PFS Algorithm**           Group 2 (MODP_1024)

Answer (score 0):

IKEv1 supported ciphers for Google Cloud VPN can be found in here[1].

[1]https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/supported-ike-ciphers